# Regex to get extra text around the match, much like getting a snippet containing the match in the given text

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a sort of snippet regex, that gets the matching text + any words before or after the match, if any. So, given the below text:

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s`

A function like `getSnippet(text, number, match)`, will get a snippet from the above, where `number` is how many words we want the result to have and `match` is the part we want to get a snippet from. So, calling `getSnippet(text,10, 'ipsum')` for the above, will return:

```
['Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and', 'and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard']
```

I am thinking that something with a look ahead and look behind should do it, but what I am not sure is the word counting. And the tricky part is if there are no matches behind, compensate those in the front, or the opposite.

Thanks

EDIT:

I don't understand the duplication closure. I am not trying to get the text wrapped by the tags, but also words before and after the tags, so a snippet. The attached questions are different from the snippet. Is anyone fully reading the question, or just the title?

Comment: please provide an example with a desired result

Comment: I already have the example there

Comment: I think the duplicate ones do give you at least part of the solution.  PLease use that and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: @RohitGupta the thing is that I know from the problem's perspective, and the definition, that they don't help in solving the issue at all. One is about wrapping the match in tags, which the question is not at all about that, becase the text already has the tags, and the second is about matching text within the tags, which again is not the main purpose of the question. Now I removed the tags in the example, so that whoever is reading these without paying attention, does not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regex which can be accomodated into a function:

```
/(\S*\s*){0,5}lorem(\s*\S*){0,5}/gi
```

It's the closest I could come up which doesn't:

1. Count all of the words
2. Compensate in the beginning or end of the snippet if the other side doesn't have enough words

This though seems to be very slow in performance with long text, so if performance is an issue, it may not be the best thing.